# Inside Aggregate communication with c# events?

Tags: c#, events, domain-driven-design, aggregate

Is it a good idea to use c# events for communication between entities inside aggregate boundaries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no need to do that. The aggregate root as entry point delegates calls to children if necessary and handles return values.

If the communication within an aggregate is so complex that you feel like you need events (eg. to inform other child entities of changes in the first child entity) your aggregate is likely to be scoped too big.

"Favor small aggregates" (Vaughn Vernon).

Answer (score 0):

An Aggregate is responsible for consistency within it's bounds (AggregateRoot). I would argue that the Aggregate should manage the communication between entities in order to ensure that consistency is maintained.